# compare a variable and an integer in bash

Tags: bash, ubuntu, conditional-statements

I have this code. But I always get an error `line 34: [24: command not found`.

It should execute the code in the if statement as soon as the do while loop executet the 24 time.

```
#!/bin/bash

input="./user.cvs"

latexStart="\\documentclass[12pt]{article}\\usepackage{labels}\\usepackage{graphicx}\\usepackage{array}\\begin{document}\\graphicspath{{./QRcodes/}}\\newcolumntype{C}{>{\\centering\\arraybackslash} m{27mm} }"

latexEnd="\\end{document}"

latexBeginLabels="\\begin{labels}"

latexEndLabels="\\end{labels}"

counter=0

touch newLabels.txt

echo "$latexStart" >> newLabels.txt

echo "$latexBeginLabels" >> newLabels.txt

while IFS=';' read -r f1 f2 f3 f4 f5 f6 f7 f8 f9 f10 f11 f12 f13
do

path="./QRcodes/$f2$f3.png"

vcard="BEGIN:VCARD%0AN;CHARSET=utf-8:$f3;$f2;;$f1;%0AADR;CHARSET=utf-8;INTL;PARCEL;WORK:;;$f10;$f11;;$f12;$f13%0AEMAIL;INTERNET:$f6%0AORG:$f4%0ATEL;WORK:$f8%0ATEL;FAX;WORK:$f9%0ATITLE:$f5%0AURL;WORK:$f7%0AEND:VCARD"

encodedVCard=$(echo "$vcard" | sed -e 's/\+/\%2B/g')

url="http://api.qrserver.com/v1/create-qr-code/?size=300x300&data=$encodedVCard"

wget -O "$path" "$url"

if ["${counter:-0}" -gt 21] ;
    then
        counter=0
        echo "$latexEndLabels" >> newLabels.txt
        echo "\\newpage" >> newLabels.txt
        echo "$latexBeginLabels" >> newLabels.txt
fi

echo "\\begin{tabular}{ C C } \\includegraphics[height=30mm]{name.png} & Name Man \\\\ \\end{tabular}" >> newLabels.txt

let counter=counter+1

done < "$input"

echo "$latexEndLabels" >> newLabels.txt
echo "$latexEnd" >> newLabels.txt
```

The error is in Line 34, `if ["${counter:-0}" -gt 21] ;`. I got this example from [Compare integer in bash, unary operator expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/408975/compare-integer-in-bash-unary-operator-expected)
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need

```
if [ "${counter:-0}" -gt 21 ]; then ...
```

i.e. your conditional statement is separated from the surrounding square brackets by spaces.

I'm quoting `counter` to be safe, but if you're sure it'll never be empty then you can skip that. It's probably better to be [safe than sorry](https://stackoverflow.com/a/605138/12960), however, and follow your original pattern.

Comment: If he doesn't mind bash-specific features, `if [[ ${counter:-0} -gt 21 ]]; then` uses double-brackets, which don't perform word-splitting on its contents.