# I am getting error "unary operator expected"

Tags: linux, shell, redhat

I am getting the error *unary operator expected at line no 5 and line 11*. 
please help to resolve this problem.

```
echo ”enter the number”
read n
q=$n
a=0
while [ $q – gt 0 ]
do
  r= `expr $q % 10 `
  q= `expr $q / 10 `
  a=`expr $a + $r /* $r /*$r `
  done
  if [ $a=$n ]
  then
    echo “the number $n is armstrong number”
  else
    echo “the number $n is not armstrong number”
  fi
done
```

Comment: Enclose your variables in double quotes and you will be fine.  Another idea is to use `[[ .. ]]` instead of `[ .. ]`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Compare integer in bash, unary operator expected](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/408975/compare-integer-in-bash-unary-operator-expected)

Comment: I think the problem on line 5 is, ***`– gt`*** should be ***`-gt`***. It should use a regular dash instead on a long dash (em dash?), and there should be no space between the dash and the letter g.

Answer (score 0):

At line number 9 you have used the forward slash instead of backslash. Also the loop end should be above the 'if' condition. If condition also should be modified as -eq .

```
echo ”enter the number”
read n
q=$n
a=0
while [ $q -gt 0 ]
do
    r=`expr $q % 10`
    q=`expr $q / 10`
    a=`expr $a + $r \* $r \* $r`
done

if [ $a -eq $n ]
then
    echo “the number $n is armstrong number”
else
    echo “the number $n is not armstrong number”
fi
```